# Why is the menu not appearing in the window?

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to add a menu into the UI but it doesn't show up. I copied everything directly from effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm but it still isn't working. I'm using Python 3 and macOS 10 if that's relevant.

```py
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('300x300')
master.title('Table')

def hello():
    print("hello")

menubar = Menu(master)
menubar.add_command(label = "Hello!", command = hello)
menubar.add_command(label = "Quit!", command = master.quit)

master.config(menu=menubar)

master.mainloop()
```

Edit: I tried the submenu but it still does not appear and the window is empty: [code and tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYr0j.png)

Comment: I tested your code and the menu Items show up and work as expected. What OS are you on?

Comment: I am on macOS 10 and I tested it with the submenu but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: I've updated my answer now that I know you are on OSX. On OSX the menubar appears where a standard menubar appears on OSX: along the top of the screen. It will not show up at the top of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX, you cannot put commands on the menubar. Also, you showed a screenshot of the window but on OSX the menubar appears at the top of the screen just like a normal Mac app.

Comment: I just tested their code and the quit command works on the root menu. Thought I do agree they should probably be using sub menus.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it appears to work just fine on my end.

Python 3.6 / Windows 10.

Here is an image showing the code in question working fine.

[image]

Like Bryan had mentioned maybe you need to be using a submenu here.

Revised code:

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.geometry('300x300')
master.title('Table')


def hello():
    print("hello")


menubar = Menu(master)
master.config(menu=menubar)
submenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
submenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=master.quit)


master.mainloop()
```

[image]